# Near future book with black holes, enviromental problems, and privacy issues

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book approx 15 years ago, set in the near future. The older people were into electronics and wore recording glasses called 'peepers'. The book also got into environmental issues, a black hole at the center of the earth and the sun, and a war against Swiss bankers

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/identify-a-near-future-book-with-automated-news-filters-and-floating-countries (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 13):

Based on the description in the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_%28novel%29) article, sounds like it could be *Earth* by David Brin.  Published in 1990 and set in 2038.  Description mentions a black hole in the center of the earth and a war that pits most of the nations against Switzerland (the banking industry).  Eyeglass cameras / overlays on real environments (peepers ?) are listed as one of the technologies he predicted in the book.  See no mention of a black hole in the Sun, but it is just a synopsis.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely _Earth_.